# How can I dynamically pass all customer IDs to the WHERE IN clause of subquery

Tags: mysql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to fetch 2nd MAX END_DATE for all listed customers by passing all customer_id to the WHERE IN clause of subquery. Right now my static customer_id in WHERE IN clause gives me the desired output but the rest customer_id shows NULL.

How can i pass all customer_id dynamically instead of static value in the WHERE IN of subquery. Would be appreciated your help.

```
SELECT d.customer_id
, ( SELECT DISTINCT g.end_date
FROM contract g
WHERE g.end_date = (SELECT MAX(g.end_date) FROM contract g WHERE g.customer_id IN ('64','65','69') 
AND g.customer_id = d.customer_id 
AND g.end_date<(SELECT MAX(g.end_date) FROM contract g WHERE g.customer_id IN ('64','65','69') 
AND g.customer_id = d.customer_id)
)) END_DATE
FROM customer_vw d
GROUP BY d.customer_id;
```

Comment: oracle-sqldeveloper works with OracleDB which is not related to MySQL. Refine your tags list.

Comment: *How can i pass all customer_id dynamically instead of static value in the WHERE IN of subquery.* For example pass this list as CSV and parse it in the query with according expression.

Comment: Your query is extremely strange. You have 2 conditions in WHERE - one of them needs `g.end_date` to be equal to the subquery output whereas another conditions needs the same value to be less that the same subquery output.

Comment: @Akina Oracle's SQL Developer works with other databases than just Oracle. You can set up a [JDBC connection to a MySQL database](https://oracle-base.com/articles/mysql/mysql-connections-in-sql-developer) and it will work with that.

Comment: @MT0 I mean that OP must clarify what DBMS is used. Either OracleDB or MySQL. Not both. The solution applicable to one of them may be not applicable to another one. The syntax of shown query does not allow to distinguish what DBMS is used.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're overcomplicating it; analytic functions might help in this case. Here's an example - I'd want to select the 2nd highest hiredate from a table per each department:

```
SQL> break on deptno
SQL> select deptno, hiredate from emp order by deptno, hiredate desc;

    DEPTNO HIREDATE
---------- ----------
        10 23.01.1982
           17.11.1981    --> this, for department 10
           09.06.1981
        20 12.01.1983
           09.12.1982    -->
           03.12.1981
           02.04.1981
           17.12.1980
        30 03.12.1981
           28.09.1981    -->
           08.09.1981
           01.05.1981
           22.02.1981
           20.02.1981

14 rows selected.
```

So:

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select deptno, hiredate,
  3       rank() over (partition by deptno order by hiredate desc) rnk
  4     from emp
  5    )
  6  select deptno, hiredate
  7  from temp
  8  where rnk = 2;

    DEPTNO HIREDATE
---------- ----------
        10 17.11.1981
        20 09.12.1982
        30 28.09.1981

SQL>
```

---

As of "dynamically passed list of values", in Oracle (as you use Oracle SQL Developer, I (maybe wrongly) presume you actually use that database) you'd *split* that list of values into rows (that's what subquery in lines #5 - 8 does) and use it in `IN` clause:

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select deptno, hiredate,
  3       rank() over (partition by deptno order by hiredate desc) rnk
  4     from emp
  5     where deptno in (select regexp_substr('&&par_deptno', '[^,]+', 1, level)
  6                      from dual
  7                      connect by level <= regexp_count('&&par_deptno', ',') + 1
  8                     )
  9    )
 10  select deptno, hiredate
 11  from temp
 12  where rnk = 2;
Enter value for par_deptno: 10,30

    DEPTNO HIREDATE
---------- ----------
        10 17.11.1981
        30 28.09.1981

SQL>
```

In SQL Developer, you'd substitute `'&&par_deptno'` with `:par_deptno` (i.e. change substitution for bind variable).

Comment: Thanks for the solution. My outer SQL was giving all customer ids and that needs to be passed in WHER IN clause of subquery. Here your solution is taking input that what i'm not looking for. It should take all IDs automatically. All IDs will come from another table and will pass on to another table that's written in the subquery.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you are saying. If IDs come from another table, then that's **JOIN** we're talking about. There's nothing **dynamic** in that. Option I posted does what you asked (OK, to be honest - what I understood you asked).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIKE` to compare to a string of comma-delimited numbers and the `DENSE_RANK` analytic function to find the second highest:

```sql
SELECT d.customer_id,
       ( SELECT end_date
         FROM   (
           SELECT end_date,
                  DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY end_date DESC) AS rnk
           FROM   contract g
           WHERE  ',' || :your_list_of_customers || ',' LIKE '%,' || customer_id || ',%'
           AND    g.customer_id = d.customer_id
         )
         WHERE rnk = 2
         AND   ROWNUM = 1
       ) AS END_DATE
FROM   customer_vw d
GROUP BY
       d.customer_id;
```

*Note: Do not use `RANK` as if there are two (or more) rows tied for first then `RANK` would return the ranks 1, 1 and 3 for joint 1st and 3rd and there would be no second place. `DENSE_RANK` solves this by returning 1, 1, 2 in the previous example.*